# Same code renders differently across different chrome profiles

Tags: css

I'm puzzled by this.  I took a screenshot to capture the (rather large) discrepancies.  In both profiles, I cleared cache/history and have caching disabled.  I've looked at the source of the .css files to confirm that the are the same, and they are.

[image]

Comment: Maybe you have scale enabled - [Ctrl] + [0] to reset. Are windows of the same size? Maybe there are media queries that render right one smaller?

Comment: Did you try pressing CTRL+0 to set zoom to default? Maybe it's set differently for each profile.

Comment: Omigosh, I feel foolish.  Thanks guys, that was the issue. :)